# java android random colors

Tags: java, android

I want my code to automatically pick random colors... at the moment I have it static... I want it when it changes color, just randomly pick any color in the world of RGB...

the below is what I have, any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

```
private float[][] BackgroundColors = { { 141, 189, 193 }, { 116, 84, 62 },
        { 73, 113, 116 }, { 193, 163, 141 },  { 15, 11, 6 }, };

private void getCurrentColor() {
    CurrentColorNumber++;
    if (CurrentColorNumber >= 5) {
        CurrentColorNumber = 0;
    }

    CurrentColor = new Color(
            BackgroundColors[CurrentColorNumber][0] / 255.0f,
            BackgroundColors[CurrentColorNumber][1] / 255.0f,
            BackgroundColors[CurrentColorNumber][2] / 255.0f, 1);

}
```

Comment: Do you need to select a random color from you list OR generate a random color ?

Comment: Is the capital variable names an android thing? I would follow best practices... it is very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I have a text view and I want a random color for the text 
on every button click.
Just check this code on your program.
I hope this logic helps you.

```
TextView Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult); 
Random mRandom = new Random();      
Display.setText("WHAT????");
Display.setTextSize(mRandom.nextInt(75));
Display.setTextColor(Color.rgb(mRandom.nextInt(265),
mRandom.nextInt(265), mRandom.nextInt(265)));
```

Comment: Although this may work, please correct your slang spelling and variable names, before posting an answer.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re  variable name doesn't metter...and in whole world not all people know English very well...i just know little english for your kind information

Comment: @JacksOnF1re    yes boss i definitely care next time

Comment: Unfortunately it seems it is not clear what I want to say, maybe it's just hard over comments. Please do not feel personally attacked.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help, this right here made a lot of sense to me, thank you so much: mRandom.nextInt(265),
mRandom.nextInt(265), mRandom.nextInt(265)

Answer (score 3):

you could use [Random](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html) to peek four numbers between 0 and 255, and then use [Color.argb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))  to return the correspondent color. E.g.

```
private Random mRandom = new Random();
private int randomColor() {
  int r = mRandom.nextInt(256);
  int g = mRandom.nextInt(256);
  int a = mRandom.nextInt(256);
  int b = mRandom.nextInt(256);
  return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

you don't need the alpha channel you can either set `a = 255`, or using 
[Color.rgb(r, g, b)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(int,%20int,%20int)) instead of [Color.argb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). Thanks to @maraca that made me notice it

Comment: so should I just remove my: private float[][] BackgroundColors = { { 141, 189, 193 }, { 116, 84, 62 },
   { 73, 113, 116 }, { 193, 163, 141 },  { 15, 11, 6 }, }; code then and use yours? extreme noob trying to learn here

Comment: If you want every time a new random color I would answer yes.

Comment: but my code will look for BackgroundColors = xxxxx, how would I integrate what you have? please help, thanks again!

Comment: why do you need to assign it to `BackgroundColors`?

Comment: you have to call `yourView.setBackgroundColor(randomColor());` or `yourTextView.setTextColor(randomColor())`

Answer (score 0):

**You can that with Random class:**

```
Random r = new Random();
BackgroundColors[r.nextInt(BackgroundColors.length)];
```